# Passing variables into twig components

Tags: craft3, variable, include

Based on this interesting article: [DRY templating with Twig and Craft CMS](https://voices.basedesign.com/dry-templating-with-twig-and-craft-cms-543292d114aa). I found myself trying to update the approach with `include` instead of `macro` following reading I had about twig 2 and craftcms 3.

So basically there is my component

**_hero-banner.twig**

```
{# Defaults #}

{% set defaults = {
    heroTitle : title is defined ? title : 'Title not set',
    titleColor : color is defined ? color : null,
    heroImage : image is defined ? image : null,
    heroButton : button is defined ? button : null,
    heroClasses : classes is defined ? classes : null
  }
%}

{# Options #}

{% set options = options is defined ? defaults|merge(options) : defaults %}

{# Variables #}

{% set imageMobile = {
    mode: 'crop',
    width: 640,
    height: 500,
    quality: 75,
    position: 'focus-point'
} %}

{# Output #}
 <div class="row c-hero-banner" {% if options.heroImage %} style="background-image:url('{{ options.heroImage.one.getUrl(imageMobile) }}')" {% endif %}>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6">
      {# Display the entries #}
            <h1 {% if options.titleColor %} class="t-text-white" {% endif %}>{{ options.heroTitle }}</h1>
            {% if options.heroButton %}
              <button type="button" class="o-button o-button--primary"> {{ options.heroButton }} </button>
            {% endif %}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And there is my include

**index.twig**

```
{% set heroBannerOptions = {
    title : homepage.mainTitle,
    image : homepage.heroBanner,
    color: true
  }
%}

{% include 'components/_hero-banner.twig' with { options : heroBannerOptions } %}
```

Somehow I cannot pass the variables into the component and I cannot figure out why...

Comment: What happens if you do `{{ dump(options) }}` in the included file?

Comment: Obviously I wasn't calling the proper variables. options.heroTitle was `null` but options.title calls the proper info! Still need to figure out how to use that properly! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to post the solution:

**_hero-banner.twig**

```
{% set defaults = {
    heroTitle : options.title is defined ? options.title : 'Title not set',
    titleColor : options.color is defined ? options.color : false,
    heroImage : options.image is defined ? options.image : null,
    heroClasses : options.classes is defined ? options.classes : null,
    heroButton : options.button is defined ? options.button: null
  }
%}

{# Options #}

{% set options = options is defined ? defaults|merge(options) : defaults %}

{# Variables #}

{% set imageMobile = {
    mode: 'crop',
    width: 640,
    height: 500,
    quality: 75,
    position: 'focus-point'
} %}

{# Output #}
 <div class="row c-hero-banner" {% if defaults.heroImage %} style="background-image:url('{{ defaults.heroImage.one.getUrl(imageMobile) }}')" {% endif %}>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6">
      {# Display the entries #}
            <h1 {% if defaults.titleColor %} class="t-text-white" {% endif %}>{{ defaults.heroTitle }}</h1>
            {% if defaults.heroButton %}
              {% include "components/_buttons.twig" with options %}
            {% endif %}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I wasn't calling my variables properly...